# Machine learning shape and type

Tags: machine-learning

in machine learning, in being trining, it works better to have given all of the same size, for example:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

or it works well this way?

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

and it is best to use them as an object, or it's OK if the object is converted to a json string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If you are doing supervised learning you need "features" and things to predict, say one or more classifications or a numbers.

Most supervised schemes can cope with some missing input features, but if the training set has target outputs/prediction it will struggle. Most unsupervised schemes can cope with some missing features, though not all of them.

As long as each index into the feature set means the same feature.

The specific format of the data will vary depending on the implementation. Being a dataframe,  object, json, ... anything shoulnd't make much difference.